# I want to update shipping charge $0 for all Woocommeerce Subscription auto-renewal orders

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

Do we have any woocommerce subscription auto-renewal hooks where we can update the shipping charges? In my case for all the auto-renewal I want to update the shipping charge to $0.

Answer (score -1):

Yes  you can do that. This is how that you can sets the shipping charge to $0 for all auto-renewal orders:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_renewal_order_shipping_total', 'set_renewal_order', 10, 4 );
function set_renewal_order( $total, $renewal_order, $original_order, $product ) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was searching filter 'woocommerce_subscriptions_renewal_order_shipping_total' throughout the plugin folder. I couldn't find any instance of that. Could you please explain more? thank you in advance.